# Casting const void* const to const char* const produces the "ignored-qualifiers" warning, why?

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-warnings

I don't understand why the following code gives the "type qualifiers ignored on cast result type" warning in GCC, can you please explain?

```
#include <stdint.h>

char f(const void* const a) noexcept {
    return static_cast<char>(*static_cast<const char* const>(a));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/n8Ws9aTcq

Comment: A simpler one-liner example would be `int x = static_cast<const int>(42);`.  You can cast 42 to an `int`, but what does it mean to cast it to a `const int`?

Comment: rolling back to your original question. Please don't change the question statement after you've gotten answers.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: your "rollback" is actually wrong, and you overwritten my correct original statement.

Comment: your original question actually had two nested static casts.

Comment: Restoring from the original godbolt link https://godbolt.org/z/699vvEvEc

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Yes, and I restored it, but 20 seconds later you overwritten it with a wrong code :) BTW, I now see that your answer was correct, I just didn't understand it as it was stated. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-class non-array prvalue cannot be cv-qualified.

This means that your `static_cast<const char* const>(a)` is exactly the same as `static_cast<const char*>(a)`, the pointer itself isn't const-qualified. It's simply discarded, which is what the warning is telling you about (the second `const` is what is being ignored)